# Issue with hiding header of Header Grid view

Tags: android, gridview, header

I have implemented HeaderGridView using [this class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java). Upon search filter, i have to hide header view to be re-shown at removing search filter. I have tried many approaches, but issue is, when header is hidden, height of gridview is reduced to barely 20-40dp even for 10+ rows in grid view.

Approaches tried:

1. headerView.setVisibility(View.GONE) and headerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
2. setting visibiliy GONE for individual text view and image view in header view.
3. setting height of header view to be 1 dp using layout params.
4. Removing header view. But issue is it cant be added again.

None of these approaches worked. Any idea how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Guys who have downvoted this... can you please suggest any other approach to do this effectively... I am sure you must have some easy to guess solution which is sure to work... and that must be reason to downvote.
and if you have not used this class of HeaderGridView, then try to implement it and let me know solution. You must be able to do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar issue has been reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77311).
Issue is with GridView.onMeasure method. The problem is, to calculate the height the child View of child(0) is used. (which is in our case the header).

If the header height is lower than the other height of the child's the calculation is wrong. And when its visibility is gone or its height is set to 1 dp, then height of scrollable area of grid view reduces.